# Macro in excel - Loop range in excel and write values to txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that loops through an excel range and writes values into a txt file.

For example, in the range A1:C3, the results in the txt file would be:

```
$A$1    ab
$A$2    abc
$A$3    abcd
$B$1    abcde
$B$2    abcdef
$B$3    abcdefg
$C$1    abcdefgh
$C$2    abcdefghi
$C$3    abcdefghij
```

In principle, I need to merge these two macros into one:

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:E6")

    For Each rCol In rRng.Columns
        For Each rCell In rCol.Rows
            Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
        Next rCell
    Next rCol
End Sub
```

and

```
Dim s As String
Dim n As Integer

n = FreeFile()
Open "/Users/Kuba/Desktop/a.txt" For Output As #n

s = "Hello, world!"
Debug.Print s ' write to immediate
Print #n, s ' write to file

Close #n
```

Thanks for any advice.
JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a nested loop to traverse the row and column numbers like so:

```
Sub LoopAndWrite()

Dim FF As Byte
FF = FreeFile()

Open "/Users/Kuba/Desktop/a.txt" For Output As #FF

For c = 1 To 3 '// columns 1 to 3 (A:C)
    For r = 1 To 3 '// rows 1 to 3
        Print #FF, Cells(r, c).Address & " - " & Cells(r, c).Value
    Next
Next

Close #FF

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, that works, but in result I missing absolute position of the value. For example in cell A1 i have value "AB". If I use your macro, in txt file will be only value AB, but i need in txt file - A1 - AB or something like that with position (A1).

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped (green tick on the left)